# HikeriCP : java.sql.SQLException: Catalog can not be null when closing a connection with explicit catalog

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I'm trying to use HikariCP in a java app to implement connection pooling to MySQL.

Because of a DB design flaw, the app uses different databases and I have to explicitly call `connection.setCatalog()` to change the database when needed.

When I try to close the connection that uses the default database (with no call to `setCatalog()` ) everything is fine and the connection returns back to the pool. But If this is a connection to another database (using `setCatalog()`) I get the following exception when I call `close()` method:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Catalog can not be null
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setCatalog(ConnectionImpl.java:5324)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolElf.resetConnectionState(PoolElf.java:263)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBagEntry.resetConnectionState(PoolBagEntry.java:122)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.ConnectionProxy.close(ConnectionProxy.java:193)
    at someapp.repository.MySqlRepository.closeConnection(MySqlRepository.java:198)...
```

Needless to say that I have checked if the catalog is null:

```
public void closeConnection() throws SQLException{
        System.out.println("trying to close with catalog:"+connection.getCatalog());

        if(connection!=null){

        //connection.setCatalog("defaultdb");
            connection.close();

        }
        this.connection=null;
    }
```

If I uncomment the the `connection.setCatalog("defaultdb")` to set the catalog back to the default, the problem still persists.

The only situation where everything is fine is when I don't use `setCatalog()` method at all.

Is this an issue with hikaricp when the catalog is explicitly set? Is there a way to close the connection and send it back to the pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @brettw, to solve this problem, you have to set a default catalog in HikariCP properties:

```
    HikariConfig conf = new HikariConfig();

    ....

    conf.setCatalog(DatabaseConfiguration.JDBC_DEFAULT_DATABASE);

    ds = new HikariDataSource(conf);
```